# Método POST não funciona!

Tags: php, post, get

Galera, estou fazendo um código simples... Só quero pegar a informação digitada no form. Mas não da certo, o GET funciona... o Post não.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
        Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" value="1">
        Idade: <input type="text" name="idade" />
        <input type="submit" value="POST"/>
    </form>
    <?php

    $nome = $_POST["nome"];
    echo $nome;
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Já tentei fazer em arquivo separado também não deu certo, é alguma coisa no php.ini?
Estou usando o XAMP tbm...

Answer (score 1):

Utilize esta forma aqui em baixo e submeta o formulário e veja se vai dar algum erro.
Aqui em casa funcionou de boa...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#" method="POST">
            Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" value="1">
            Idade: <input type="text" name="idade" />
            <input type="submit" value="POST"/>
        </form>
        <pre>
            <?php
            // Habilitar a exibição de erros em tempo de execução.
            ini_set("display_errors", "on");
            // Depurar a super global POST.
            print_r($_POST);
            // Testar a tipagem da super global POST.
            var_dump($_POST);
            ?>
        </pre>

    </body>
</html>
<?php
$nome = $_POST["nome"];
$idade = $_POST["idade"];
echo "Olá $nome, você tem $idade ano(s)... legal!!!";
?>
```

O Retorno será:

> Array (
>       [nome] => 1
>       [idade] => 33 ) array(2) {   ["nome"]=>   string(1) "1"   ["idade"]=>   string(2) "33" }
>            Olá 1, você tem 33 ano(s)... legal!!!

Answer (score 0):

Localize no seu `php.ini` a linha `enable_post_data_reading`. Altere para `on`:

```
enable_post_data_reading = on
```

[Documentação PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.enable-post-data-reading):

> Desabilitar esta opção faz com que $_POST e $_FILES não sejam
>   preenchidos. A única forma de ler dados postados será através do
>   stream wrapper php://input. Isto pode ser útil para intermediar
>   requisições ou para processar dados POST de uma maneira eficiente em
>   termos de memória alocada.

Answer (score -4):

Ola,

Se você esta inserindo o PHP na mesma pagina do formulario, você deve alterar seu action do form:

DE:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
```

PARA:

```
<form action="<?=($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" method="POST">
```

Comment: Por quê exatamente isso resolveria o problema?  Qual a diferença entre o `PHP_SELF` e colocar o nome do arquivo direto? E quanto ao problema de XSS?

Comment: Você ja tentou habilitar os erros do php.ini?
display_errors = on